# Apache RewriteMap with wildcard

Tags: apache-httpd, rewrite, mod-rewrite

We want to migrate multiple domains on new servers. In the first step (though from a SEO point of this is not recommendable) everything has to be redirected to the new domain's root.

Later the team wants to have more fine grained redirects (thus the usage for RewriteMaps)

I thought of using something like this:

```
^/(.*)    https://www.newdomain.com/
```

But it seems I am on the wrong track

Answer (score 0):

While the map itself does not have wildcards or regexes or anything of the sort, two options come to mind:

- the *usage* of the map can take [a default value like so](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html#introduction):

  RewriteRule "^/ex/(.*)" "${examplemap:$1|/not_found.html}"
- the rewritemap does not need to be a simple text/hash map, it [could be an external program](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html#prg), if it really really needs to be, and that program could do whatever it wants to arrive at the replacement.